# What is the proper way to derive percentage from decimal

Tags: notation, percentages

I have been thinking about this for a while, and I want to know what the proper way to convert a decimal into a percentage is. Say you have a word problem that needs you to convert a decimal, say for instance 0.7, into a percentage. There would be 2 ways to do it:

```
0.7*100%=70%
```

or

```
0.7*100=70%
```

which is more correct? The first way has the flaw in which 100%=1. So the equation should rightfully be 0.7*100%=0.7. However in the second equation, the percentage is removed but the percentage sign at the very end of the equation pops up without warning. Which would be the proper way to calculate percentage in a word problem.

Comment: What is a "word problem"? As long as you can discern when you refer to a percentage and when you refer to a decimal I can't see the issue.

Comment: The first is "dimensionally correct". If you have e.g. $1=100\%$ it invites the question $100\%$ of what?

Comment: I would say your first method is more "proper". If you've taken any science classes like physics or chemistry, you'll have converted between different units. For example, to convert from meters to kilometers you would do $1\text{m} \left(\frac{1\text{km}}{1000\text{m}}\right) = 0.001 \text{km}$. If you consider "%" as a unit and "0.7" as unitless, then your situation mirrors this.

Comment: To clarify the calculation of @FullofDill, multiplying by $1$ is always legal and will never change the value of anything. Also, since $1\mathrm{km} = 1000\mathrm m$, we can take that equality, and divide it by $1000\mathrm m$ on both sides to get $\frac{1\mathrm{km}}{1000\mathrm m} = 1$. Since that fraction is the _same thing_ as $1$, we can freely mulltiply by it without changing the value of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It might be helpful to keep in mind:
>
> - The term *percent* is just a shorthand for *hundredth*, i.e. $\frac{1}{100}$. So whenever you say *x* percent this is the same as when saying: x-hundreth.

It follows $\color{blue}{0.7\cdot100\%}=0.7\cdot100\cdot\frac{1}{100}=\frac{70}{100}\color{blue}{=70\%}$ is correct, while the second statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write
$$
.7 = 70/100 = 70\%.
$$
In other words, $70\%$ is literally just another notation for the number $70/100$, or $.7$.

Instead of saying, "$70\%$ of the cars are blue", it would be equally valid (if a bit strange-sounding) to say, "$.7$ of the cars are blue."

Answer (score 0):

If it would make you more confident in your conversions, you could write
$$
(0.7 \times 100)\% = 70\%.
$$